# Inno Setup - Renaming MsgBox Title Bar

Tags: inno-setup

This is my code:

```
[Code]
procedure CurStepChanged(CurStep: TSetupStep);
  var
  ErrorCode: integer;
begin
  if CurStep = ssPostInstall then
  begin;
    if MsgBox('Czy chcesz zainstalować pakiet DirectX9?', mbConfirmation, MB_YESNO) = IDYES then
    begin
    ShellExec('', ExpandConstant('{src}\directx\dxsetup.exe'), '', '', SW_SHOW, ewWaitUntilTerminated, ErrorCode);
    end;
  end;
end;
```

It is possible to rename title only of this one MsgBox? Suppose I want to create another MsgBox and i want have 2 another titles for example: Instalator #1, Instalator #2. The change in language files will affect on both MsgBox'es.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) You can change titles for all message boxes (and also for all dialogs) in your .isl file located in Inno Setup installation directory:

Edit *Languages\Polish.isl* (in your case) or *Default.isl* (for English) and change **SetupAppTitle** to your desired value.

[image: App title]

2) You cannot set different titles to various MsgBox-es as Inno Setup does not support this, but you can implement your own MSgBox dialog like regular Windows form and set title that way.

Comment: OK. I understand. Tkanks for explain.